# How to solve the problem with starting an Android App on Boot?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've just read a ton of similar questions, but nothing helped at all.

In the code below I'm trying to perform a starting an app right after unlock of my granny's old phone and show her the only button to enter Viber.

OnBoot Activity

```
class OnBoot : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED == intent.action) {
        val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(i)
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    

    <receiver android:name=".OnBoot">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

MainActivity

```
fun openApp(view: View) {
    val launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(".com.viber")

if(launchIntent != null){
    startActivity(launchIntent)
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this , "No package", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

So, app doesn't start even on Emulator. Seen comments like "Check weird permission on Xiomi emulator", mine is Pixel 2. Also, I know that Viber package name is wrong and I know where it should be, but cannot find it in emulator, would appreciate the hint in comments.

Maybe any ideas with the task?